# Proving that the fundamental group of a finite Galois category is profinite

Tags: ct.category-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups, automorphism-groups

This is sort of a cross-posting of [this question of mine over on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4419486/690489).

Suppose that I am given a finite Galois category $(\mathcal{G}, F)$, i.e. a Galois category in the sense of SGA 1. One of the crucial properties of such a category is that the group of natural automorphisms $Aut(F)$ is profinite, and it seems to me that this ought to be a natural consequence of the fact that the fibre functor $F: \mathcal{G} \to FinSets$ is pro-representable by definition (in fact, I think you can show that the pro-object of $\mathcal{G}$ that represents $F$ is the diagram of isomorphism classes of Galois objects in $\mathcal{G}$). However, most proofs of this fact that I have seen (for example, [in the Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BMQ)) seem to not make use of the fact that $F$ is pro-representable.

Is there a good explanation of why pro-representability is not usually made use of in this proof, and what might be a way to crucially make use of pro-representability in a proof of the fact that $Aut(F)$ is profinite ?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "finite Galois category" That the fibre functor is valued in finite sets?

Comment: @DavidRoberts By "finite Galois categories" I meant Galois categories as defined in SGA 1 or the Stacks Project. I say this to distinguish them from the infinite Galois categories in Bhatt and Scholze's paper on the pro-étale topology. But to answer your question, yes, the fibre functor is valued in finite sets.

Comment: I thought about it for a bit, but the way that the implication "pro-representable implies profinite automorphism group" can work in this case (note that this implication is not correct in full generality) uses exactly the same ingredients as a proof that the automorphism group is profinite with no pro-representability assumption. So I don't think there is such a way

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Would you mind explaining in details how "pro-representability implies profinite automorphism group" uses exactly the same ingredients as a proof that the automorphism group is profinite with no pro-representability assumption ? Also, what might be a reason why $Aut(F)$ should not be profinite in general, even if it is pro-representable ? I have seen counter-examples, but I can't pinpoint an underlying (categorical) reason why it should fail in general.

Comment: I mean if you are representable, you are pro-representable, but not all groups are profinite, yet all groups appear as automorphism groups of certain functors. So it's really the fact that you land in $Fin$ that plays a role. Once you see that, you see that pro-representability can play no specific role because it must use, one way or another, that you land in $Fin$, but also, landing in $Fin$ (no pro-representability) is enough to ensure that you are profinite.